# How do I commit two changes to the same file separately in Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Consider a situation: I've made multiple changes to one versioned file and want to commit the changes. Now I realise that they'd better be committed as two separate commits - so that some changes belong to one changeset and others - to another. How can I do that most efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the file, use svn diff to undo the changes for the second changeset, commit the modified file with the first changeset, copy the file back, commit second changeset.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether TortoiseSvn supports Hunk selection. TortoiseHg (for mercurial) does, so I assume Tortoisesvn does so too.

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not support this

Comment: Ok thanks. I think it could be implemented the way Aaron explained though.